# Regex in Custom package in C# i want capture (meta:resourcekey =".......")

Tags: c#, regex, customtool

DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            TextDocument activeDoc = dte.ActiveDocument.Object() as TextDocument;

```
        var text = activeDoc.CreateEditPoint(activeDoc.StartPoint).GetText(activeDoc.EndPoint);


        var input = (text);

        var regex = new Regex(@"(\bresourcekey\b+) = ");

        var match = regex.Matches(input);

        string matches = string.Empty;

        foreach(var item in match)
        {
            matches += item.ToString() + " "; 
        }

        MessageBox.Show(matches);
```

My regex command are fault(i know)but i want capture meta:resourcekey = "......" from my messagebox text i want only .... part of my capturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is plain regex

> meta:resourcekey[\s]*=[\s]*\"(.*?)\"

And here is c# Example

```
var mydata = "meta:resourcekey = \"something\"";
Regex regex = new Regex("meta:resourcekey[\\s]*=[\\s]*\"(.*?)\\\"");
foreach (Match htmlPath in regex.Matches(mydata))
{
    Console.WriteLine(htmlPath.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        TextDocument activeDoc = dte.ActiveDocument.Object() as TextDocument;

        var text = activeDoc.CreateEditPoint(activeDoc.StartPoint).GetText(activeDoc.EndPoint);


        var input = (text);

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(meta:resourcekey)+(\W)+(\w*)+(\W)");

        var match = regex.Matches(input);

        string matches = string.Empty;

        foreach(var item in match)
        {
            matches += item.ToString() + " "; 
        }

        MessageBox.Show(matches);
```

I found the answer like that.That makes Scann the current page code and write to text and finally getting meta:resourcekey="something" all of the code pages... Write to MessageBox